# Can't transfer bookmarks from Midori-Granite to Midori

Tags: midori

I tried using Midori-Granite for a while.  But it seems that every so often, it crashes.  So, instead, I started using regular ol' Midori.  While this one works, I can't seem to see my bookmarks under Midori.  I tried exporting the bookmarks from Midori-Granite and importing them into Midori, but that didn't work, either.  So is there a way to transfer my bookmarks from Midori-Granite to Midori?

Comment: Which way you are installing Midori?

Comment: I'm installing it via Synaptic, from the default repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've installed Midori from the Software Center (or otherwise from the upstream Ubuntu repositories), you're running Midori 0.4.3. You can verify this by accessing the "About" dialog at the bottom of the gear menu.

The Midori that we build with Granite enabled is version 0.5.10. There's been a lot of work done in Midori regarding bookmarks between these versions. If you want the latest Midori without Granite (The one that is compatible with your bookmarks), you'll need to get it from the Midori PPA.

You can add the Midori PPA and install Midori from it by entering the following in Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:midori/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install midori
```

Comment: I shall try that repository.
_tries that repository_
Looks like that version of Midori is working well.  Thank you, Daniel, for your input.