# Midori crashes when trying to play YouTube in fullscreen

Tags: midori, video-player

On a fresh install of elementary OS Freya 0.3.2, Midori crashes repeatedly, when I am trying to play a full screen YouTube video. It works fine in the normal mode. Also, I installed the codecs that it asked to install the first time I tried playing a YouTube video. I have not updated the system even once. Also, the player used is the HTML player.

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: So did you upgrade Midori or use Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Both. However, using Chrome was much better than the upgraded Midori.

Comment: Yes, I use Chrome too

Comment: Please update youtube to the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Midori is very about of date and old.The only solution is to install Chrome or Firefox or wait for elementary OS Loki (which should update it)

You can also try https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1185/3757 to update Midori